# mysql ssl connection with no certs

Tags: mysql

We have weird argument going on at my work.One of the developer is claiming that an ssl connection(secure connection) can be made by a client to the mysql database server without using ssl certs.Is it possible if yes, any documentation you can refer online, I checked online couldn't find any.

If above one is possible without certs, can someone point me the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Tunnel MySQL over SSH: http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html may have some value - perhaps not exactly what you are asking for. Also [MySQL+SSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-connections.html) require certs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SSL with mysql, but SSL/TLS itself supports connections without certificates by using ADH ciphers (and others). Of course this needs some other way to prove the identity of the server to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks, so  browsers usually don't support this.